# both read and modify a .txt file in python

Tags: python-3.5

How can i both read and modify a *.txt* file in **python**?

I am trying to write a programme using which i modify a text file using given user input. But if i use ***'r'*** within ***open***, it only reads.

I have tried:

```
sanskrit = open("sanskrit.txt","r")
sans = sanskrit.read()
print(sans)
sanskrit.close
```

Error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/AnuragEK/coding/try.py/", line 3,in 
sans = sanskrit.read()
```

Can anyone help me?

**Thanks** in advance.

Comment: The code you posted does not exhibit the error you posit. Please clarify; see also the help guidance for creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to both read and write from/to a file, you should use the mode `'r+'` instead of `'r'`.  There are [a few other modes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for doing this but `'r+'` is probably the one you want.